# Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. When running php bin/magento cron:run

Tags: php, cron, magento2

I'm using Magento ver. 2.2.6 with PHP 7.1 on a Shared Hostgator hosting.

I'm trying to install and run the cron job.

Every time I try to do any SSH command, I get Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Solution, move aways from Hostgator hosting to a A2hosting solution and all the problem were solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you check your PHP version? Did you ensure your PHP CLI has also the correct version? Please run php --version on your shell where you run bin/magento

Comment: We have figured out that the Hostgator server we are using doesn't have the correct PHP CLI